# why $A\cong A/aA\times A/bA$ when $char(A)=ab$ and $(a,b)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

if $A$ is a ring with $char(A)=ab$ and $(a,b)=1$, can someone explain why the Chinese remainder theorem implies $A\cong A/aA\times A/bA$? i know that TCR implies directly $A/aAbA\cong A/aA\times A/bA$ but i'm confused why $aAbA$ must be $(0)$?

Comment: It's because of the condition on the characteristic.

Comment: least integer such thath n1=0, but JCAA's answer is what i needed. Thanks!

Comment: If it is what you need, you should accept it. Otherwise it will look like the question does not have an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the ring homomorphism
$$
f\colon A\to A/aA\times A/bA,\qquad f(x)=(x+aA,x+bA)
$$
Its kernel is $aA\cap bA$. If $x=ay=bz$, for $y,z\in A$, we get
$$
ax=abz=0,\quad bx=bay=0
$$
If $ma+nb=1$, which is guaranteed by Bézout's identity, then
$$
x=(ma+nb)x=0
$$
Therefore the homomorphism $f$ is injective.

It is also surjective, because if $x,y\in A$, we can consider $x-y=am(x-y)+bn(x-y)$, so we can set
$$
z=x-am(x-y)=y+bn(x-y)
$$
and $z-x\in aA$, $z-y\in bA$, so
$$
(x+aA,y+bA)=(z+aA,z+bA)=f(z)
$$